# Disable colorful separator in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

How can I disable these colorful separators in PhpStorm ?

[image: See this for more information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Appearance`
3. Disable `Enable HTML/XML tag tree highlighting` option

[image]